# xtz preso em simplestaking.com

Tags: xtz

When I try send XTZ from my adress validated by TREZOR T WALLET, it (simplestaking.com) shows that mensage "the sum of gas consumed by all the operations in the block exceeds the hard gas limit per block" as i show on images attach.

PLEASE, WHAT SHOULD I DO TO PROCEED WITH THAT OPERATION WELL SUCESSED?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not our fault; probably don't shout at _us._

Answer (score 0):

Simply try again. If a block has too many transactions, it will reach the internal limits and be rejected. This is temporary. This is not your fault nor the fault of trezor nor your wallet software.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://briskett.app/ for Trezor T instead.
Simplestaking doesn't seem to be in development.